# try to use pyqt5 and speech recognition, program window give me no response

Tags: python, pyqt5, speech-recognition

I am learning how to use speech recongnition in a GUI application, I want my app always listening for the keyword "hello", but while listening my gui always show no response, I don't know if its normal or not the app won't crash, python is still printing "hello" when "hello" is heard. how can I do to fix the GUI no response?

```
import sys
import pyaudio,os
import speech_recognition as sr
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QLabel,QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore

r=sr.Recognizer()

def Listen():
    while 1:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listen")
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            user = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(user)
            if "hey" in user or "Hey" in user:
                print("Hello")
        except:
            print("sorry")
    

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QWidget()   
    widget.setWindowOpacity(.10)
    screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    widget.setFixedSize(480,960)
    w = widget.geometry()
    x = screen.width() - w.width()
    y = screen.height() - w.height()
    widget.move(x,y)
    widget.show()
    Listen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


window()
print("window open")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: your while loop blocks and freezes the gui while it is running.

Comment: @Alexander is there a way to continue listen and gui won't freeze

Comment: It might work if you put the listener in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the speech_recognition logic in a separate thread.

For example:

```
import sys
import pyaudio,os
import speech_recognition as sr
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QLabel,QDesktopWidget,
from PyQt5 import QtCore

def Listen(r):
    while 1:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listen")
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            user = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(user)
            if "hey" in user or "Hey" in user:
                print("Hello")
        except:
            print("sorry")


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):

    def run(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        Listen(r)

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QWidget()   
    widget.setWindowOpacity(.10)
    screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    widget.setFixedSize(480,960)
    w = widget.geometry()
    x = screen.width() - w.width()
    y = screen.height() - w.height()
    widget.move(x,y)
    thread = Thread()
    thread.start()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```